# All Of is not working properly in Open API Swagger 3.0

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

In my project I am using Open API 3.0 to for generating mmodel classes.

My requirement is to I have to reuse the parent class attribute to sub class.

Ex:

```
public class Student {
  private String id;
  private String name;
}

public class Address {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String city;
  private String state;
}
```

But the problem is allOf generating the bean class like below instead of above one.

```
public class Address {
  public Student student;
  private String city;
  private String state;
}
```

Below is my schema.yaml

```
Student:
    properties :
    id:
      type: integer
      format: int64
      description: The ID of the new account
    name:
      type: string
      description: The human-readable description of this account
    

Address:
    properties : 
    allOf:
        $ref : '#/Student'
    city:
       type: string
      description: City
    state:
      type: string
      description: State
```

How to make sure the properties are duplicating instead of creating Object.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: It seems that `allOf` doesn't do what you expect it to do. According to the [Swagger Documentation](https://swagger.io/specification/#schemaComposition) `allOf` is used for composition (meaning that in your example `Address` is composed of a reference to a `Student` and some additional fields)

Comment: Thanks Thomas!!!I understood the purpose of allOf. Is there any other way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

You can define separate sections under the `allOf` element. First section is the reference to your parent object. Second section is an object with the additional properties.

The following is correctly parsed in https://editor.swagger.io :

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: "example"
  version: "1.0"
paths:
  /example:
    post:
      responses:
        "200":
          description: example
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Address'
components:
  schemas:
    Student:
        properties:
          id:
            type: integer
            format: int64
            description: The ID of the new account
          name:
            type: string
            description: The human-readable description of this account
        
    Address:
      allOf:
      - $ref : '#/components/schemas/Student'
      - type: object
        properties:
          city:
             type: string
             description: City
          state:
            type: string
            description: State
```

Comment: Thanks JAck. But If I am defining like this I am getting access denied error. java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\test\src\main
\resources\schema\v0_1 (Access is denied)

Comment: You may  be using spring security then you have to provide permission for resources folder from your security config file : -  .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()